How to define the EF on complex object?
I try to create code and use Entity Framework for saving this data into a database.
I have tried many ways to insert it into the table, using the function OnModelCreating, but each time I get error.
Thanks for any help.
This is the code:
public class BreakTime
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public TimeOnly Start { get; set; } 
    public TimeOnly End { get; set; } 
}

public class WorkTime
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; } 
    public TimeOnly OpenTime { get; set; } 
    public TimeOnly CloseTime { get; set; }

    public List<BreakTime>? Breaks { get; set; } 
}

public class WeeklyWorkSchedule
{
    // size 7 => one for each day
    public WorkTime[] WorkTimes { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public WeeklyWorkSchedule Schedule {get;set;}
}

public DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

